# How to convert type var into type string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, var

This is my code,

```
 var getURL = tc.provideCreden("location/", "42.3", "-71.06");
```

This gives a `var` value. I want to convert this into `string` to use with my another method.

That means,

```
var getReviews = getRe("this is a string");
```

I want to use `getURL` value as this string. How can I do that?

this is my first method **provideCreden()**

```
  public dynamic provideCreden(string subUrl, string Latitude, string Longitude)
        {
            string fullURl = BaseUrl + subUrl + apiKey;
            WebClient tripClient = new WebClient();
            var finalResult = tripClient.DownloadString(fullURl);

            RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(finalResult);
            var final = obj.Data
                        .Where(s => s.latitude == Latitude && s.longitude == Longitude)
                        .Select(n => n.Apidetailurl);

            return final;
        }
```

this method return **http://api.somevalue.com/api/partner/2.0/localized/** this. then when I convert this using ToString() it gives **System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[some.Item,System.String]**

so I want the this **http://api.somevalue.com/api/partner/2.0/localized/** as the value.becaue I want to use it in another method.

Comment: you can use .ToString()

Comment: Just an FYI, there is no such thing as 'type var'. `var` is not a type. `var` simply asks the compiler to infer the type for you. In your example, we have no idea what `getURL` is, so although the below answers recommending `ToString()` *might* be correct, it's not definitely the right way to go.

Comment: `var ` is not a type, and not a magical word. It is just a way to tell compiler to choose the type implicitly according to the return type of `provideCreden`. **What is the `provideCreden`, what type is it? Show its definition.**

Comment: provideCreden returns a string(url),then I want to use that string(url) in another method with string parameter.ToString does not behave the way I want.that's why I'm asking

Comment: when I use var it gives `http://api.somename.com/api/partner/2.0/location/` this url. but when I use ToString(), it gives `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[somename.Item,System.String]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToString(getURL);`. This also handles if your `("location/", "42.3", "-71.06")` snippet returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns `IEnumerable<TResult>` which I am suspecting TResult of type String.
However, your return type is of type `dynamic` so better to change dynamic to whatever the type it is returning eg `public  IEnumerable<String> provideCreden(string subUrl, string Latitude, string Longitude)` . Then you can do this:

```
 var getURL = tc.provideCreden("location/", "42.3", "-71.06").FirstOrDefault();

//check the getURL. If of type String no conversion needed.
var getReviews = getRe(getURL);
//If not try 
var getReviews = getRe(getURL.ToString());
```

I hope this helps. BTW do check things like if getURL is null.

Comment: thanx for your try, but this is not workin.`'object' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'`

Comment: Oh yes.. its dynamic... what is the type for Apidetailurl??

Comment: it gets from the database. when I put a breakpoint and looked. it look like this `http://api.someurl.com/api/partner/2.0/loction/8`

Comment: if you change signature to public  IEnumerable<String> provideCreden(string subUrl, string Latitude, string Longitude) ... does this work? I know I am going blind here but looks like its just IEnumerable of string...

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyVar = "love";
string MyString = MyVar.ToString();
```

Comment: Try to avoid code only answers, they don't actually help provide information as to the solution to the problem. Perhaps add a tidbit about ToString being accessible on all objects and a link to documentation to support it instead of just showing this example?